# How to show base64 image in a new tab using javascript in ios

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am getting a base64 data of an image. I want to open that image in a new tab. For that I did the code like,

var window = new window();

window.open("<iframe src="+base64Url+");

This is working in chrome(android) but same thing is not working in chrome (ios) or even in Safari(ios).

Can anyone please help me out in this??

Thaks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write the image outerHTML to the newly opened window's `document`:

```js
var image = new Image();
mage.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
```

Comment: I tried this way also...but not working in ios devices. Any idea why it is not working in ios??